# Relational database structure logic configuration

Tags: mysql, database, logic, structure, relational-database

I'm going to develop a relational database on server side with MySql RDBMS.

Since this database will contain many informations and there will be many simultaneous queries, i'd like to setup an optimized structure to avoid slow processes when retrieving datas.

My main table called "account" will contain information about name, surname ecc.. of users:

```
 TABLE 'account'

 ID - NAME - SURNAME - AGE

 Primary key -> 'ID'
```

The second table will be called "file" and has an id (foreign key referring account.id), a filename and a column called 'count':

```
 TABLE 'file'

 ID - FILENAME - COUNT

 Primary key -> {'ID','FILENAME'}

 Foreign key -> 'ID' -> 'account.ID'
```

My last table is called 'visit' and has this structure:

```
 TABLE 'visit'

 ID - FILENAME - OPTION

 Primary key -> {'ID','FILENAME'}

 Foreign key -> 'ID' -> 'account.ID'
 Foreign key -> 'FILENAME' -> 'file.FILENAME'
```

While first table won't contain many rows, second table could have something like thousands of rows and third table hundreds of thousands rows.

Maybe i'm wrong (i'm not an expert about db system management and optimization :D), but if i make simultaneous queries on 'visit' table with so many rows and joined with other tables, the process could become slow.

Is this structure good or can be improved?

Last question, can i update automatically 'file' -> 'count' column with the count of rows contained in 'visit' where 'file.filename' = 'visit.filename' when 'visit' table is updated ?

Or it's better to make a query like 'SELECT count(*) from ecc..' every time?

Hope i explained myself, thanks.

Comment: Recording 'age' is usually not a good idea; it becomes wrong quite quickly (on average after 6 months, sometimes the next day).  The job of the DBMS is to ensure that queries work well.  The table structure is reasonable.  You could perhaps use a trigger to update the count, but it is usually better not to store derivable data because something ends up going wrong and a wrong answer is worse than a slow answer.

Comment: For the second part of your question, it's better to query for the count every time. SQL servers are fast, and optimized for this information as long as the data is indexed (it is in your example).

Comment: @mrunion Primary key -> {'ID','FILENAME'} is considered primary as couple, so could exist ID('A') - FILENAME('A') and ID('A') - FILENAME('B') into 'file' table

Comment: Yeah, I caught that and had already edited my post. But thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to what you comment, your idea sounds good, but everything depends on the business, ie business logic — if you are considering make daily reports,
weeks, monthly visits; if the business is interested in knowing the history of
visits in the last 10, 20 or 30 years.  Depending on that, you could create from time to time historical data tables with a period of time (it may be a year).

As you can see there are many ways, and you should also take into account the part of business
the technical side, such as disk space, backups, etc, how important is to keep
historical data and for how long.

**EDIT**:

Regarding your second question, yes you can, if you implement a trigger. But you can check this nice link to ensure if you're making a good decision to create a trigger. (I don't like copy and paste so I prefer share the link, if I'm breaking the rules , please do me know)

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/123074/sql-triggers-and-when-or-when-not-to-use-them

**UPDATE V.2.0:**

Suggestions:

1. Try to not use restricted names on your column names (like count,option),  <strike>I don't exactly if</strike> there are restricted on mysql <strike>but in SQL SERVER yes</strike>, so <strike>for portability</strike> is better not use names like this.
2. Like Jonathan Leffler says, its not a good idea save the age, you can prefer save a birthdate.

Comment: Thanks, is trigger better than select count() every time for performance?
Consider that requests will be made every second or minute, on each table since these are the main tables. There are other tables but less important.
About history, content will never be deleted and should be always available.

Comment: I didn't say erase data, i said backup or save in history table by year, something like table visit_2013, visit_2014. It depends of the business.

Comment: @lubilis: How often is the count going to change — any of the counts?  If it is less than once a second, using a trigger probably won't matter.  If it is thousands of times a second, a trigger may become a serious bottleneck.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thank you for edit, here is a nice link about when use triggers and when not, http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/123074/sql-triggers-and-when-or-when-not-to-use-them.

Comment: @Juan Ruiz backup tables seems to be a good idea, especially when there are some conditions verified. For example if a row is inserted in file table on 2015, i won't query in table visit_2013 and visit_2014, but only in visit_2015 table. Otherwise i'm forced to join tables.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks for the link, the count is going to change from a minimum to once an hour to a maximum of one hundred at second, more or less.

Comment: In this case, forget the trigger.

Comment: It wasn't me who gave the link.  Hundreds per second requires some care.  It isn't impossible, but be cautious and measure.  I'm inclined to agree with "forget the trigger", though.